# Get return value of a command with AppleScript (to get IP address and use as a string)

Tags: applescript

I am trying to get the current local IP address using AppleScript so that I can use this to form a URL string, like so:

```
"http://" & ip & ":8080"
```

Research has lead me to this command which will return the correct IP:

```
ifconfig en0|grep "inet "|cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

I need to save the value of that command so that I can use it in my AppleScript. How can I achieve this? Or is there a better way to get the IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
set tIP to do shell script "ifconfig en0|grep 'inet '|cut -d ' ' -f 2"
set tURL to "http://" & tIP & ":8080"
```

Answer (score 2):

In native applescript...

```
set ipAddr to IPv4 address of (get system info)
set urlAddr to "http://" & ipAddr & ":8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that 'get system info' will return only the first IP address that it finds. For example my machine has two network interfaces, ethernet on 'en0' and WiFi on 'en1' the call only returns the address on 'en0'. So if you have multiple interfaces this might not be the call you want.

```
system info
    --> {..., IPv4 address:"10.10.15.89", ...}
```